# Using Typeahead from Twitter Bootstrap in a form (formtastic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

How do I integrate a typeahead from bootstrap like this:

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="8" data-source='["University of Pennsylvania","Harvard","Yale","Princeton","Cornell","Brown","Columbia","Dartmouth"]'>
```

into a standard form like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@education) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.input :college, placeholder: "Update Education" %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I didn't read your whole question! I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your controller

```
def index
  @autocomplete_items = Model.all
end
```

In your view, just like you have with an additional ID for the selector...

```
<% semantic_form_for(@education) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :college, placeholder: "Update Education", id: "auto_complete" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And most importantly, pass the `@autocomplete_items` instance variable defined in your controller into a Javascript variable in your view:

```
<%= javascript_tag "var autocomplete_items = #{ @autocomplete_items.to_json };" %>
```

This will serialize your data and make it usable JSON for the Typeahead function to use.

As for the Typeahead, simply pass that object (`@autocomplete_items`) as JSON to the Javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#auto_complete').typeahead({source: autocomplete_items});
    });
</script>
```

Additionally there is an [Autocomplete gem for Rails 3](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) which will work directly with your models rather than passing off the object to your Javascript. There is even a Formtastic example in the documentation.

**Edit:** It looks like I didn't read your whole question! Unfortunately HTML5 Data Attributes are currently unsupported with Formtastic. There is however a [separate branch](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/pull/673) that does include support for these attributes.

Other than that there's always just sticking with Good ol' HTML/ERB for dynamic features like this...

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="8" data-source='<%= @autocomplete_items.to_json %>'>
```

**EDIT 2:** I've just noticed two things. First being the way I was passing the JSON object to a Javascript variable (see the example). Secondly, the above example using HTML5 data attributes will *not* work with Twitter's Typeahead plugin, but it will work with the [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)  plugin.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm kind of new at this, but I can't seem to get either the method you wrote or the Autocomplete gem to work.. As for your method, where do I place that javascript? I made a model called University that just has in it university names, and I made a controller called universities_controller and placed the index method in that. Still, the typeahead isn't working. Help please?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? And is the problem with the Ruby code or the Javascript?

Comment: I just noticed that the way that I was passing the JSON into the Javascript code would yield issues. I've gone ahead and fixed that by using the `javascript_tag` helper, and passed the variable off using ERB.

Answer (score 2):

I got it worked like:

Controller

```
 @categories = Category.find(:all,:select=>'name').map(&:name)
```

and views

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="8" data-source='<%= @categories.to_json %>'>
```

Comment: Instead of `@categories = Category.find(:all,:select=>'name').map(&:name)`you can also do the shorter `@categories = Category.uniq.pluck(:name)`.

Comment: This will work well with smaller datasets, but if they get large, the time it takes to process all the records prevents the typeahead from working quickly. For a large dataset, you need to use a query instead of returning all of the json in on chunk.

Comment: I agree for low dataset this will be quick. 
For large sets, using ajax will be better option. There are multiple examples of typeahead ajax.

Comment: Just to note, I believe in Rails 3.2 and after, Category.pluck(:name) instead of Category.find(:all,:select=>'name').map(&:name) will be faster and more efficient.