# How to get typeahead/autocomplete text to refer to foreign id in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been working on getting this Twitter Bootstrap typeahead to work and right now I can get a list of all my data when I start typing it into the form, but when I submit, the values do not get passed in as IDs. Is there any way for me to pass in an id number based on the autocomplete selection?

Here's the code I'm using...

```
  <%= f.text_field :cargo_to_load_id, :data => { provide: "typeahead", source: Cargo.order(:name).map(&:name) , items: "9" } %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794306/using-typeahead-from-twitter-bootstrap-in-a-form-formtastic   this place could help u out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I need to have these getter and setter methods in my model file. These will then do the work of finding the corresponding id.

```
  def cargo_to_unload_name
    cargo_to_unload(:name)
  end

  def cargo_to_unload_name=(name)
    self.cargo_to_unload = Cargo.find_by_name(name)
  end

  def cargo_to_load_name
    cargo_to_load(:name)
  end

  def cargo_to_load_name=(name)
    self.cargo_to_load = Cargo.find_by_name(name)
  end
```